# How do I close a mechanize browser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm running into an error in mechanize for python in which valid links that I try to open with it gives me the following error:

```
urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

And it's not a problem of mechanize not being able to open them because when I open them in interactive Python using mechanize, there is no error. So I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with too many mechanize browsers being open.

How would I close a mechanize browser?

Is there a command like br.close()?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, there is a [`close()`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/068fc642ae705aa0c71732db4b77d342e5b23628/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L142) method on a `Browser` instance:

```
br.close()
```

Comment: What if I don't close instance? Is there any default time after which it closes automatically?